# Set update_all_types to true on ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to add some additional properties to my mappings, in this specific case I want to modify a title field in my English index so that it would use the english analyzer.

Should be pretty straightforward, except that I have a title field in quite some types, and it seems to be not possible to do this.

The error I have is the following : Set update_all_types to true to update [search_quote_analyzer] across all types.]

But I am not able to find a single reference on how or where to set this 'update_all_types' parameter.

This is the very simple code I use in Sense :

```
PUT /my_index/_mapping/my_type
    {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "english"
        }
      }
    }
```

So, how can I make this work if the same field is used in other types ?

This is the error message :

```
"type": "illegal_argument_exception",
"reason": "Mapper for [title] conflicts with existing mapping in other types:
  [mapper [title] has different [analyzer], mapper [title] is used by
  multiple types. Set update_all_types to true to update [search_analyzer]
  across all types., mapper [title] is used by multiple types. Set
  update_all_types to true to update [search_quote_analyzer] across
  all types.]"
```

So it seems I need to set 'update_all_types:true' somewhere, but the documentation fails on that part.

Comment: If you use the search feature in the documentation, you'll land on the [proper page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/indices-put-mapping.html#merging-conflicts) ;-)

Comment: Ouch, seems I overlooked that one. 

Anyway, doesn't seem to work either as now I get a different error, I'll update the original post

Comment: Most probably that the field `title` in your other type already has a different analyzer (i.e. not the same as the analyzer of `title` in type `my_type`). Possible? Can you show the output of `GET my_index` ?

Comment: Allow me to add it later as I have no access to my dev environment right now. I can state that none of the titles have anything but the type field at this stage. I do have 3 different types with a title, and a few other (equal) fields. At this moment  it is still easy to just rebuild from scratch, but I want to avoid this when I am close to production stage.

Comment: If you ever rebuild it, you might want to read this first: https://www.elastic.co/blog/index-vs-type

Comment: thanks for the link, clear that it's important to define all correct, but I believe the example I just added is not conflicting with the limitations (at least, as far as I understood)

Comment: Was there ever a correct solution for this? I'm running into the same issue and nothing here has done me any good =/

Answer (score 15):

You can find the documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html) !

The `update_all_types` is a get parameter to give like that :
`PUT my_index/_mapping/type_one?update_all_types`

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue, try the code below to update all types:

```
   PUT /my_index/_mapping/my_type?update_all_types
    {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "english"
        }
      }
    }
```